# How To Add Arms To A Character

Tags: modeling, workflow

[image]

[image]

I dont know how to add arms to my character without destroying his round body shape. If I add shoulders, his overall body shape becomes rectangular, wich I don’t want. I rather want to  exaggerate the round torso, by adding arms, not destroying it. If someone has an idea please let me know.

Comment: check how to cut round holes in spheres: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=round+hole+in+sphere+blender  ... then extrude a cylinder

Comment: The arms could be tubes that are completely separate geometry that intersect the torso, but are not PART of the torso.